# Is there a way to enable a button if at least one checkbox is checked with knockout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to see if I can find a knockout equivalent for this bit of jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/BPhZe/76/

This is what I have to far, but all the items are bound to the same observable so it obviously doesn't work.

**html:**

```
<form>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option-1" id="option-1" data-bind="checked: buttonEnabled"> <label for="option-1">Option 1</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option-2" id="option-2" data-bind="checked: buttonEnabled"> <label for="option-2">Option 2</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option-3" id="option-3" data-bind="checked: buttonEnabled"> <label for="option-3">Option 3</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option-4" id="option-4" data-bind="checked: buttonEnabled"> <label for="option-4">Option 4</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option-5" id="option-5" data-bind="checked: buttonEnabled"> <label for="option-5">Option 5</label>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="button" value="Do thing" data-bind="enable: buttonEnabled">
</div>
</form>
```

**javascript:**

```
var viewModel = {
    buttonEnabled: ko.observable(true)
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dludlow/WdWEW/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. See the updated jsFiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/WdWEW/4/

I did a few things.

1. I added a unique `value` attribute to each of the checkboxes
2. I bound the checkboxes to a new property on the view model named `options` which is an observableArray
3. I changed `buttonEnabled` to a computed property that returns `true` if the `options` property has a length greater than zero.

Here's the updated view model.

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.options = ko.observableArray(),
    this.buttonEnabled = ko.computed(function() {
       return self.options().length > 0;
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Here's the updated view:

```
<form>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-1" id="option-1" value="1" data-bind="checked: options"> <label for="option-1">Option 1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-2" id="option-2" value="2" data-bind="checked: options"> <label for="option-2">Option 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-3" id="option-3" value="3" data-bind="checked: options"> <label for="option-3">Option 3</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-4" id="option-4" value="4" data-bind="checked: options"> <label for="option-4">Option 4</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-5" id="option-5" value="5" data-bind="checked: options"> <label for="option-5">Option 5</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Do thing" data-bind="enable: buttonEnabled">
    </div>
</form>​
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks. I was thinking it would have something to do with a computed observable.